# Fitting an activation function with tanh

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm trying to fit an activation function with tanh via:
`F = aa3 + aa2 * np.tanh(aa0 * x + aa1)`

However, the original data (blue) is peculiar in that it needs an asymmetric curvature which the fit (red) is unable to grasp - sharp at the base and loose at the top:
[tanh fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZdRW.png)

Is there a better function you might recommend? Any general advice to think on going forward would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps this is the wrong place for this? Any suggestions of proper stackexchange forum would also be appreciated if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain an asymmetric curvature one can use a function of this kind (A generalized logistic equation) :
$$y(x)=y_{min}+\frac{y_{max}-y_{min}}{1+a\:e^{-b\,x}+\alpha\:e^{-\beta\, x}}$$

[image]

Comment: Deleting my old comment, I got your equation to work - thanks so much!

Comment: Do you know of a consistent method to read the slope of the linear portion from this graph. From experimenting, I'm seeing that the inflection point looks like it's stored in b or Beta (and can alternate between the two on different fits).

Comment: May be I can give an easy method. But first I have to test it. I need the data on numerical form (not a graph) : On excel folder or  .txt preferably ( two distinct files, one for the x's and one  for the y's ).

Comment: I've put the 2 .txt (with tab delimiters) in a public repo: https://github.com/evanseitz/sharing ; I was able to load these in using np.loadtxt('xlist.txt'); thank you! Also, for the fit, ymin = 5.99, ymax = 11.99, a1 = .006, b1 = 3.39, a2 = 1.66, b2 = .67

Comment: @ees. Hi ! Sorry I have not much available time to study deeply your problem. Nevertheless I used the data to propose two methods in order to compute the slope of the linear portion of the curve. This is posted in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the slope of the linear portion of the curve is another problem. That is why I post a second answer.

FIRST METHOD (arduous)

One use a non-linear regression software to fit the equation $\quad y(x)=y_{min}+\frac{y_{max}-y_{min}}{1+a\:e^{-b\,x}+\alpha\:e^{-\beta\, x}}\quad$ to the data. I didn't it in order to save time. Instead I used your result of fitting : $y_{min} = 5.99\:,\: y_{max} = 11.99\:,\: a_1 = 0.006\:,\: b_1 = 3.39\:,\: a_2 = 1.66\:,\: b_2 = 0.67$

Then one compute the derivatives $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Solving the equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ leads to the abscissa of the inflexion point. Then one compute the ordinate and the slope with $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Thanks to a math software the result is :
$$\begin{cases} x_i=0.733087 \\ y_i=8.965789 \\\frac{dy}{dx}=y'_i=1.006941\end{cases}$$ 
The equation of the tangent at inflexion point is : $y(x)=y_i+(x-x_i)y_i'$ as drawn on the next figure :

[image]

Note : One can see that the tangent is a very good fit only for a few points close to the inflexion point. This is not a good fit for the linear portion of the curve. So the above value of the slope can be condidered as a rough approximate.

SECOND METHOD :

Let $\begin{cases} 
y_m=y_{min}+C(y_{max}-y_{min}) \\
y_M=y_{max}-C(y_{max}-y_{min}) 
\end{cases}\quad$ 
with for example$\quad C=0.2\quad \begin{cases}y_m=7.19 \\y_M=10.79 \end{cases}$

One determines the corresponding range of $k$ :

[image]
Result : $\quad k_{min}=490\quad,\quad k_{max}=530$ .

Then one proceed to a linear regression on the range $k_{min}\leq k\leq k_{max}$ .
$$y=Ax+B$$
[image]

Result : $\quad A=0.892462 \quad,\quad B= 8.292967$ .

The fitted staight line is drawn on next figure.

[image]

One can see that the fitting is better than above on a larger range. The drawback is that the method is a bit subjective because the result is slightly dependant of the factor $C$ which has to be reasonably chosen ( about $0.1<C<0.3$ ).

Note :An idea to make it less subjective should be to compute $x_m$ and $x_M$ instead of choosing the factor $C$. This might be done thanks to the method given pages 17-19 in https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf . Since I didn't tested it with your data I cannot recommend it.

Comment: Oh nice, thank you so much for this detailed assessment! Luckily, I have room for computation time, but you're right, C creates another round of optimization that I may try to avoid at first. I'll do some more testing and definitely let you know; I like the second derivative option, but also need a line that best approximates the entire linear section (very specific).

Comment: Just thinking, but after method 1, I may actually try to then use your second method: fit the tangent line (equation of the tangent at the inflection point) back through the data points in the linear portion of the original function; while constraining the new tangent line to remain uncurved. I don't think I read it right at first, but that's really cool. Will let you know.